# Asp.net Textbox displayed side by side

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, textbox

[image: Two Textboxes side by side]
Hello guys I just started designing form with asp.net tags and would like to achieve what's on the image exactly. Thanks guy

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you have already tried, and tell us what your _specific_ problem was with that. This is not a place where you just drop off your requirement, and then someone will write it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will read it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you right, this is the code you need:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and the result:

[image: Result]

Add some styles to make it pretty.

Blockquote

Here is the code with labels (you can also use asp labels):

```
<div style="display: inline-grid">
    <asp:TextBox  runat="server"></asp:TextBox><label>textbox1</label>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-grid">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox><label>textbox2</label>
</div>
```

and the result:

[image: Result 2]

You can also put the style in the css.

Comment: Yes something like that but i need a Label underneath each of the textboxes. Thanks

Comment: Please see the image i attached. Thanks

Comment: See my edit, i think this is what you want. If not, maybe provide what you already have done.

Comment: Thank you MrMaavin that what i what just tried it out it works.